# Save State iOS - Save Value when leaving application - Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I want to save the state of my application on iOS.
The app's workflow is to select a PersonID and base on that ID, a page with Details is opened. When I click on the Person's Address, the Maps is opened... but when I get back to my application, the first page is display, not the selected PersonID's page.

How can I keep the state of the application on iOS... I couldn't find something in the documentation.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **[User Defaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/user-defaults)** in Xamarin iOS to save the `PersonID` when selecting it, and get it to show the specified view when launching the app next time.

Save the `PersonID`:

```
var plist = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
int personid = 1;
plist.SetDouble(personid , "PersonID ");
```

And get it to show next time:

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{
    var plist = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;

    var personid = plist.DoubleForKey("PersonID");
    if (null != personid)
    {
       // load the matched data
    }
}
```